# Get firebase child values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to refer the below "l" value in firebase.

[image]

I have the question about, how to refer the underlined id (It is a auto generated ID at the singup in firebase authentication.)

Here is the code I have tried.

```
private String driverID = "";
DatabaseReference driverLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VehicalLocation").child(driverID).child("l");
driverLocationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

At the debug it shows, it skips the child(driverID) as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The value of `driverID` is an empty string.  As such, it's not part of the path to the database node.  You'll have to make sure `driverID` has the correct value.  Realtime Database requires that you know the full path to the node you want to query - there are no wildcards.

If you don't know the ID, then you'll have to query the parent node "VehicalLocation", and get **all** of its children, and iterate through them.

Comment: Can you explain to me, how should I change my code? I'm very very new to android. I have tried this coding by watching couple of youtube videos. I feel very hard to connect all of them together to write the exact coding.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have set String driverID = ""; so there is no driverID.
Just for the sake of running this code, for now, Hard code Key which is under VehicleLocation and set that to driverID and it will work.

Comment: Well, If the `driverID` changes in time to time. I mean when the driver logs out, that ID will not be available at "VehicalLocation". When another driver logs in that will changes according to his credentials. So how should I query this from firebase?

Comment: I'm supposing your driverID is under Users -> Driver.

So I'll suggest you to name your key 'Id' under Driver and set that id value.
Users -> Driver -> {id: "value"}

so to fetch VehicleLocation first you need to get the id of a driver from User-> driver then use that id to fetch VehicleLocation